# how to add row id to table sql

Tags: sql

I have a very naive question. What is the most simple way adding a column of row id to a table. No need to sort, partition or do any other thing, just adding a row_id like 1, 2, 3 ... N.

I am using spark sql. I am aware "zipWithIndex" can do it in spark, but I am more interested in how to accomplish it with sql.

Comment: Did you google? This is very simple

Answer (score 1):

zipWithIndex would suite for your use case. 
zipWithIndex RDD function which does the same as row_number() 
Below is the example:

```
val z = sc.parallelize(100 to 120, 5)
val r = z.zipWithIndex
r.collect
res11: Array[(Int, Long)] = Array((100,0), (101,1), (102,2), (103,3), (104,4), (105,5), (106,6), (107,7), (108,8), (109,9), (110,10), (111,11), (112,12), (113,13), (114,14), (115,15), (116,16), (117,17), (118,18), (119,19), (120,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

I need a frame of reference.  What database type?

A quick answer is modify the table through a user interface.  Add an column called row_id as an identity field.  It will automatically increment.

You can do the same functionality through sql.